# Вывод в цикле лишь одного элемента (php) с определенным id

Tags: php, циклы, twig

есть цикл, в нем выводяться записи с базы данных, в нем есть следующее условие "{% if loop.index != 1 and loop.index % 6 == 4 %}"
Оно выводит определенный идентификатор но дублирует запись, то есть вместо одной записи с определенным id выводиться две с одинаковым id.

Возможно кто то подскажет как это исправить или покажет свой вариант вывода данных таким образом.
Ниже полный код цикла.
Благодарю!

```
{% if tarifs|length %}
{% for tarif in tarifs %}
{% if loop.index != 1 and loop.index % 6 == 4 %}

Здесь html развертка с выводом переменных

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения, в коде всё верно. Была допущена ошибка с дублированием кода вывода вида модуля на странице:

```
{{ module('tarif','frontend','get_slider2') }}
```